# Keep rows if several columns (with similar names) follow a condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to check if the values of several columns follow a condition, the columns have similar names, and what I've tried is this

```
filter(df.w.meth.mean, cov.CD34.1 > 4 & cov.CD34.2 > 4 & cov.CD34.4 >4 & cov.CD34.5 >4 & cov.CD34.6 > 4)
```

How can I simplify this?
I was thinking in using grep to keep the columns that have 'cov' pattern, but is not working.
Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, using `grep` we can find out columns which starts with `"cov"`. We subset those column and select rows where all the values are greater than 4.

```
cols <- grep("^cov", names(df.w.meth.mean))
df.w.meth.mean[rowSums(df.w.meth.mean[cols] > 4) == length(cols),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr::filter_at()` you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

df.w.meth.mean %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("cov.CD34")), ~ . > 4)
```